# How does protobuf-net handle readonly fields?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, readonly, il

I use protobuf-net to serialize/deserialize my data.

I have some rather simple classes, so that's no real problem.

As far as I know, protobuf-net uses IL generation to create serialization/deserialization code. While I have readonly fields in my model, I wonder how is it possible to write to such a field with IL? I can plainly see it works well, but I don't know why...

I've tried to spy it in the code, but it's a bit too complicated.

My attempts to generate such code myself always result in IL validator errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, I can't get it to *fail* - at least, when generating in memory.

Let's start simply, with a `public readonly` field (so we aren't breaking any accessebility rules); my first attempt is as below, and it works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
class Foo
{
    public readonly int i;
    public int I { get { return i; } }
    public Foo(int i) { this.i = i; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var setter = CreateWriteAnyInt32Field(typeof(Foo), "i");
        var foo = new Foo(123);
        setter(foo, 42);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.I); // 42;
    }
    static Action<object, int> CreateWriteAnyInt32Field(Type type, string fieldName)
    {
        var field = type.GetField(fieldName,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var method = new DynamicMethod("evil", null,
            new[] { typeof(object), typeof(int) });
        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, type);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return (Action<object, int>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object, int>));
    }
}
```

The only time it gets interesting is if the field is `private`:

```
private readonly int i;
```

The code above then gives the oh-so-vague:

> Operation could destabilize the runtime.

But we get around that by pretending that the method is inside the field's declaring type:

```
var method = new DynamicMethod("evil", null,
    new[] { typeof(object), typeof(int) }, field.DeclaringType);
```

Some other internal checks can be done by enabling `skipVisibility`:

```
var method = new DynamicMethod("evil", null,
    new[] { typeof(object), typeof(int) }, field.DeclaringType, true);
```

However, note that not all of this is possible if generating standalone assemblies. You are held to much higher standards when creating actual dlls. For this reason, the `precompiler` tool (to pre-generate assemblies) cannot handle quite the same range of scenarios that the in-memory meta-programming code can.

Comment: I'll check it right away. Maybe my issue was not strictly related to readonly fields. The funny thing is that my code works on Mono and does not on .NET.

Comment: Doh. I failed to provide DeclaringType. But now I wonder - why does it work? Shouldn't a readonly field be writable only from the object's constructor? Thanks for an answer, anyway.

Comment: @PiotrZierhoffer a lot of things are only enforced at the compiler, and in full `PEVerify`. Ultimately, you can change `readonly` fields via reflection, and serializers/materializers often **completely skip** the constructor, so if that was the case there would be no way to assign a value

Comment: It should be noted that Dynamic Methods **do not allow** IL verification inside a full-trust context (i.e. a normal desktop app). Thus if you can do something with a dynamic method, that doesn't prove it's legal. If your code is doing something unverifiable (unsafe or even completely nonsensical), the JIT will happily compile it anyway. I reported this as a bug (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/332363/dynamic-methods-cannot-be-error-checked-lcg-lightweight-codegen) but MS declined to provide a way to verify dynamic methods.

Answer (score 2):

As I am quite interested in this discussion, I have tried Marc Gravell's example code and... it throws `VerificationException` on MS .NET 4.0.

I've managed to make it work but I needed to use `DynamicMethod` constructor with `owner` parameter set to `field.DeclaringType` even in case of public `i` field. `SkipVisibility` parameter seems to be redundant in this case.

PS. I believe that this entry should be a comment, but due to the lack of rep I'm unable to comment other's answers.

Comment: Well, I haven't run Marc's code, only analysed it, but the point seems to be valid.